# Hair dynamics hair jumps, jitters, and flies around

Tags: modeling, particles, cloth-simulation, hair, alembic

How can I control the hair dynamics so that the hairs mostly maintain their original shape but also move around slightly with the model when animated?

My current hair setup causes the hair to fly around and jump to different places even when the model is still. Additionally, the hair particles seem to jitter and shake and don't seem to stabilize over time.

Video with hair animation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1njqf.jpg

I've tried playing around with pin goal strength, voxel grid size, density target and strength, stiffness and mass - but my current settings don't improve the situation. Thanks in advance!

[image: Hair settings]

[image: Hair flying around]

Comment: younf found the answer? Iam dealing with same problem since 4 weeks , i tried everythung , iam done with blender